# Implementing a function to find whether it is possible to split array in pairs of equal number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a function to split array in equal parts and return true else false.

a=[2,4,4,2] should return true as we can split in [2,2] and [4,4]

a=[4,4,4] should false

a=[2,4,5,2] should return false

```
def soln(n):
    
    # traverse array element 
    for i in range(0, n) : 
       
        # add current element to left Sum 
        leftSum += arr[i]  
    
        # find sum of rest array elements (rightSum) 
        rightSum = 0 
        for j in range(i+1, n) : 
            rightSum += arr[j]  
    
        # split poindex 
        if (leftSum == rightSum) : 
            return true 
       
    
    # if it is not possible to split array into 
    # two parts 
    return false
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Edit your question and put the code in the question body. Indentation is very important in python, so be sure to use a code block.

Comment: How do `[2, 2]` and `[4, 4]` have equal sums?

Comment: Your description of the problem is really not clear.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual task. It's calculating sums, not checking for equal elements.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can be very useful here, it will give you the number of occurrences for each element:

```py
from collections import Counter

Counter([2,4,4,2])
#Counter({2: 2, 4: 2})
```

```py
from collections import Counter

def soln(arr):
    counter = Counter(arr)
    
    if len(counter) != 2:
        return False
    
    element_counts = list(counter.values())
    
    return element_counts[0] == element_counts[1]

print(soln([2,4,4,2]))
# True
print(soln([2,4,4,3]))
# False
```

Comment: thanks!  this is what i wanted!

Comment: @JimB Why is your code summing the list elements if you just want the counts to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python you can do it as follows:

```py
def check_if_partable(given_list):
    dictionary = {}
    for i in given_list:
        if i in dictionary:
            dictionary[i] += 1
        else:
            dictionary[i] = 1
    for v in dictionary.values():
        if v % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True
```